# How to measure network service quality?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

How can I say if my network as a quality service?

According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service ), an example on how to measure the service quality is high bit rate, low latency and low bit error probability. This suggestion made me ask myself if there is any standard about the indicators that should be measured... and how should they be measured.

I kept searching and found that bit rate can be obtained by sending a large file to some (?) point and then doing some math to get the goodput; and that latency can be obtained by pinging. Is there a better way to measure these indicators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit on the three major measures of network quality: Throughput, Latency, and Drop Rate. There are many other ways a network might be measured; such as switching fabric, ability to provide prioritization, and uptime. Without a specific goal or problem however, there's no better answer I could provide.

Throughput is best measured by something more application specific, like `iperf`. But transferring a large file will be roughly accurate. The `ping` utility will measure latency, and given time, drop rates. If course it's best not to measure either - it's best to design a network for a given set of conditions and requirements, then monitor the equipment itself for key performance indicators.